# Uncaught ReferenceError: detail is not defined

Tags: javascript

When I run the code below in chrome,

I got error "Uncaught ReferenceError: detail is not defined";

I try to define object shape with the name hamburgers and then to create the hamburger.

what is wrong in the code

Many thanks.

```
function Hamburger(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;

}

var shape = {
    hamburgers: [],
};

function drawshape(x, y, w, h) {

alert(x+' '+y+' '+w+' '+h);

}

shape.details = 
[
    {   
        "detail" : 0,
        "hamburgers" : [{"x" : -290, "y" : -140,"w" : -290, "h" : -140}]

    }   
];

 i = 0;
shape.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(detail.hamburgers[i].x, detail.hamburgers[i].y,detail.hamburgers[i].w,detail.hamburgers[i].h));

for(var i=0;i<shape.hamburgers.length;i++) {
        var hamburger = shape.hamburgers[i];
        var x = hamburger.x;
        var y = hamburger.y;
        var w = hamburger.w;
        var h = hamburger.h;
        drawshape(x, y, w, h);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`detail` isn't defined because you are actually trying to find `shape.details[0]`. Defining `detail` as that array item fixes it.

http://jsfiddle.net/EaPr7/

Answer (score 0):

`detail` is indeed not defined.  Try this:

```
detail = shape.details[0];

i = 0;
shape.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(detail.hamburgers[i].x, ...
```